# using in clause in ibatis

Tags: java, sybase, ibatis

Hi i'm using ibatis 2 and trying to query a table with 3 types of parameters.
below is the code

```
<parameterMap id="getSearchLateJob_Param" class="java.util.HashMap">
    <parameter property="jobSet" javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/>
    <parameter property="job" javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/>
    <!-- <parameter property = "currentJobStatusStrArr" javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/> -->
    <parameter property = "currentJobStatusArr" javaType="java.util.List" jdbcType="ARRAY"/>
</parameterMap>

<statement id="getSearchLateJob" parameterMap="getSearchLateJob_Param"  resultMap="getCurrentJob_r">
     select a.JOBSET as "JOBSET",
        a.JOB as "JOB",
        a.JOB_NO as "JOB_NO",
        a.QUALIFIER as "QUALIFIER",
        b.JOB_AVG as "JOB_AVG",
        a.STATUS as "STATUS" 
    from  CA_JOB_STATUS a,JOB_AVG b
    where a.JOBSET = b.JOBSET
        and a.JOB=b.JOB
        and a.JOBSET like ?  
        and a.JOB like ?    
        <!-- and a.STATUS in -->
        <dynamic prepend="and a.STATUS in ">
            <iterate property= "currentJobStatusArr"  open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">
              #currentJobStatusArr[]#
            </iterate>
        </dynamic>
    order by a.END_TIME desc, a.START_TIME desc                                          
</statement>
```

It still gives me an error for input parameter not set index 2

Please help as to what is wrong in this approach.

Comment: Maybe it is because you are missing the other needed parameters on your parameterMap. You put on your query: JOBSET, JOB, JOB_NO, QUALIFIER, JOB_AVG and STATUS and on your map there is only: jobSet , job and currentJobStatusArr. On iBatis you should put equivalent parameter in the map.

Comment: no no... the query works fine, if i remove the list parameter. and for those parameter its just a select and i'm not sending any inputs for those.

Answer (score 0):

I ignored the parameterMap attribute totally and modified the statement to the below:

```
     <statement id="getSearchLateJob" parameterClass="map" resultMap="getCurrentJob_r">
      select a.JOBSET as "JOBSET",
        a.JOB as "JOB",
        a.JOB_NO as "JOB_NO",
        a.QUALIFIER as "QUALIFIER",
        case when year(a.START_TIME) = 1900 then null else a.START_TIME end as "EXPECTED_START_TIME",
        case when year(a.END_TIME) = 1900 then null else a.END_TIME end as "END_TIME",
        datediff(mi,a.START_TIME,a.END_TIME) as "DURATION",
        b.JOB_AVG as "JOB_AVG",
        a.STATUS as "STATUS" 
    from  CA_JOB_STATUS a,JOB_AVG b
    where a.JOBSET = b.JOBSET
        and a.JOB=b.JOB
        and a.JOBSET like #jobSet:VARCHAR#
        and a.JOB like #job:VARCHAR#    
        <!-- and a.STATUS in -->
        <dynamic prepend="and a.STATUS in ">
        <iterate property= "currentJobStatusArr"  open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">
        #currentJobStatusArr[]:VARCHAR#
        </iterate>
        </dynamic>
    order by a.END_TIME desc, a.START_TIME desc                                          
</statement>
```